# how to specify the name of my daemon process using pydaemon

Tags: python, daemon

I'm using pydaemon ( http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/ ) to make a friendly daemon. How do I give it a name? by default it's called 'python' but I want something more meaningful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the process name cannot be done from plain Python, and pydaemon is 100% Python. You need a C-level library like [py-setproctitle](http://code.google.com/p/py-setproctitle) to do that. Then, simply add the following to your main method:

```
try:
  import setproctitle
  setproctitle.setproctitle('my-awesome-program')
except:
  pass # Ignore errors, since this is only cosmetic
```